# Finding correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, self-study, variance, covariance, expected-value

if I have A and B with the following known variables:
with $E[A]$, $E[B]$ , $\sigma_{A}$ , $\sigma_B$
and correlation coefficient: $\rho_{AB}$  (assign numbers if you like)

Say: $C=0.6A+0.4B$
Then how can I find $\rho_{AC}$?

I know how to find: $E[C]$ ,$Var[C]$, but not how to find $\rho_{AC}$...
I hope someone can help me out..

Comment: **Hint:** you can solve this using the [properties of covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties), specifically bilinearity.

Comment: Terrific! If you think you've found the answer, I encourage you to post it below!